# Building a circular facepile of profile pictures in Swift: how to have the last photo tucked under the first?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to build a `UIView` that has a few `UIImageView`s arranged in a circular, overlapping manner (see image below). Let's say we have N images. Drawing out the first N - 1 is easy, just use sin/cos functions to arrange the centers of the `UIImageView`s around a circle. **The problem is with the last image that seemingly has two z-index values!** I know this is possible since kik messenger has similar group profile photos.

The best idea I have come up so far is taking the last image, split into something like "top half" and "bottom half" and assign different z-values for each. This seems doable when the image is the left-most one, but what happens if the image is the top most? In this case, I would need to split left and right instead of top and bottom.

Because of this problem, it's probably not top, left, or right, but more like a split across some imaginary axis from the center of the overall facepile through the center of the `UIImageView`. *How would I do that?!*

[image]

### Below Code Will Layout UIImageView's in Circle

You would need to import `SDWebImage` and provide some image URLs to run the code below.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class EventDetailsFacepileView: UIView {
    static let dimension: CGFloat = 66.0
    static let radius: CGFloat = dimension / 1.68
    
    private var profilePicViews: [UIImageView] = []
    var profilePicURLs: [URL] = [] {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }
    
    func updateView() {
        self.profilePicViews = profilePicURLs.map({ (profilePic) -> UIImageView in
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.sd_setImage(with: profilePic)
            imageView.roundImage(imageDimension: EventDetailsFacepileView.dimension, showsBorder: true)
            imageView.sd_imageTransition = .fade
            return imageView
        })
        self.profilePicViews.forEach { (imageView) in
            self.addSubview(imageView)
        }
        self.setNeedsLayout()
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let xOffset: CGFloat = 0
        let yOffset: CGFloat = 0
        
        let center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width / 2, y: self.bounds.size.height / 2)
        let radius: CGFloat =  EventDetailsFacepileView.radius
        let angleStep: CGFloat = 2 * CGFloat(Double.pi) / CGFloat(profilePicViews.count)
        var count = 0
        for profilePicView in profilePicViews {
            let xPos = center.x + CGFloat(cosf(Float(angleStep) * Float(count))) * (radius - xOffset)
            let yPos = center.y + CGFloat(sinf(Float(angleStep) * Float(count))) * (radius - yOffset)
            profilePicView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos),
                                          size: CGSize(width: EventDetailsFacepileView.dimension, height: EventDetailsFacepileView.dimension))
            count += 1
        }
    }
    
    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let requiredSize = EventDetailsFacepileView.dimension + EventDetailsFacepileView.radius
        return CGSize(width: requiredSize,
                      height: requiredSize)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll have much success trying to split images to get over/under z-indexes.

One approach is to use masks to make it *appear* that the image views are overlapped.

The general idea would be:

- subclass `UIImageView`
- in layoutSubviews()
- apply cornerRadius to layer to make the image round
- get a rect from the "overlapping view"
- convert that rect to local coordinates
- expand that rect by the desired width of the "outline"
- get an oval path from that rect
- combine it with a path from self
- apply it as a mask layer

Here is an example....

I was not entirely sure what your sizing calculations were doing... trying to use your `EventDetailsFacepileView` as-is gave me small images in the lower-right corner of the view?

So, I modified your `EventDetailsFacepileView` in a couple ways:

- uses local images named "pro1" through "pro5" (you should be able to replace with your `SDWebImage`)
- uses auto-layout constraints instead of explicit frames
- uses `MyOverlapImageView` class to handle the masking

Code - no `@IBOutlet` connections, so just set a blank view controller to `OverlapTestViewController`:

```
class OverlapTestViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let facePileView = MyFacePileView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        facePileView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(facePileView)
        
        facePileView.dimension = 120
        let sz = facePileView.sizeThatFits(.zero)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            facePileView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: sz.width),
            facePileView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: facePileView.widthAnchor),
            facePileView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            facePileView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        facePileView.profilePicNames = [
            "pro1", "pro2", "pro3", "pro4", "pro5"
        ]
        
    }
    
}

class MyFacePileView: UIView {
    var dimension: CGFloat = 66.0
    lazy var radius: CGFloat = dimension / 1.68
    
    private var profilePicViews: [MyOverlapImageView] = []
    
    var profilePicNames: [String] = [] {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }
    
    func updateView() {
        self.profilePicViews = profilePicNames.map({ (profilePic) -> MyOverlapImageView in
            let imageView = MyOverlapImageView()
            if let img = UIImage(named: profilePic) {
                imageView.image = img
            }
            return imageView
        })
        
        // add MyOverlapImageViews to self
        //  and set width / height constraints
        self.profilePicViews.forEach { (imageView) in
            self.addSubview(imageView)
            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: dimension).isActive = true
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        }
        
        // start at "12 o'clock"
        var curAngle: CGFloat = .pi * 1.5
        // angle increment
        let incAngle: CGFloat = ( 360.0 / CGFloat(self.profilePicViews.count) ) * .pi / 180.0

        // calculate position for each image view
        //  set center constraints
        self.profilePicViews.forEach { imgView in
            let xPos = cos(curAngle) * radius
            let yPos = sin(curAngle) * radius
            imgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor, constant: xPos).isActive = true
            imgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: yPos).isActive = true
            curAngle += incAngle
        }
        
        // set "overlapView" property for each image view
        let n = self.profilePicViews.count
        for i in (1..<n).reversed() {
            self.profilePicViews[i].overlapView = self.profilePicViews[i-1]
        }
        self.profilePicViews[0].overlapView = self.profilePicViews[n - 1]

        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2
        
    }
    
    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let requiredSize = dimension * 2.0 + radius / 2.0
        return CGSize(width: requiredSize,
                      height: requiredSize)
    }

}

class MyOverlapImageView: UIImageView {
    
    // reference to the view that is overlapping me
    weak var overlapView: MyOverlapImageView?
    
    // width of "outline"
    var outlineWidth: CGFloat = 6
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // make image round
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.size.width * 0.5
        layer.masksToBounds = true

        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        
        if let v = overlapView {
            // get bounds from overlapView
            //  converted to self
            //  inset by outlineWidth (negative numbers will make it grow)
            let maskRect = v.convert(v.bounds, to: self).insetBy(dx: -outlineWidth, dy: -outlineWidth)
            // oval path from mask rect
            let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: maskRect)
            // path from self bounds
            let clipPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds)
            // append paths
            clipPath.append(path)
            mask.path = clipPath.cgPath
            mask.fillRule = .evenOdd
            // apply mask
            layer.mask = mask
        }
    }
    
}
```

Result:

[image]

(I grabbed random images by searching google for `sample profile pictures`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In case of less then 3, seems like the masks start colliding with undefined results. For example, use 3 images and set radius to 22 (with dimension set to 33). Any advice on fixing that?

Comment: Certainly, with edge cases like only one image, or only two images, or three images with unusual radius / dimension / outlineWidth / etc, I can see potential for issues. Should be pretty simple to account for though. I tried your suggestion of *3 images and set radius to 22 (with dimension set to 33)* and it seemed fine (although very small, and odd looking due to the very little overlap area).